# array filtering and map dynamically in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, dictionary, filter

i have a json like this:

```
[
  {
    "part": "LM",
    "section": "021",
    "column": "001",
    "description": "Descrizione attività/passività",
    "type": "NUM"
  },
  {
    "part": "LM",
    "section": "021",
    "column": "002",
    "description": "Assenza cause Ostative Applicazione Regime",
    "type": "CB"
  },
  {
    "part": "LM",
    "section": "042",
    "column": "001",
    "description": "Differenza su reddito",
    "type": "NUM"
  },
  {
    "part": "LM",
    "section": "050",
    "column": "006",
    "description": "Perdite non compensate - Eccedenza 2018",
    "type": "NUM"
  }
]
```

and i wanna map items splitted for section prop.
Aspect output is:

```
      <div>section 021
        <p>column 001</p>
        <p>column 002</p>
      </div>

      <div>section 042
      <p>column 001</p>
      </div>

      <div>section 050
      <p>column 006</p>
      </div>
```

How can dynamically pass the section prop as filter parameter?

I have tried something like:
obj.filter((item) => item.section == "021").map((item) => ... and works but i want the "021" is dynamic for every value in the object.

Thank you very much guys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to group by the array values dynamically in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390145/how-to-group-by-the-array-values-dynamically-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      part: 'LM',
      section: '021',
      column: '001',
      description: 'Descrizione attività/passività',
      type: 'NUM'
    },
    {
      part: 'LM',
      section: '021',
      column: '002',
      description: 'Assenza cause Ostative Applicazione Regime',
      type: 'CB'
    },
    {
      part: 'LM',
      section: '042',
      column: '001',
      description: 'Differenza su reddito',
      type: 'NUM'
    },
    {
      part: 'LM',
      section: '050',
      column: '006',
      description: 'Perdite non compensate - Eccedenza 2018',
      type: 'NUM'
    }
  ];

  const output = Object.values(
    data.reduce((b, a) => {
      if (b.hasOwnProperty(a.section)) b[a.section].columns.push(a.column);
      else {
        a.columns = [a.column];
        b[a.section] = a;
      }
      return b;
    }, {})
  );
  // console.log(output);

  return (
    <div>
      {output.map(obj => (
        <div>
          {obj.section}
          <ul>
            {obj.columns.map(col => (
              <li> {col} </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

View here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-txmy72?file=src/App.js

Comment: The reduce is right, but mapping to react component I need to test

Comment: @sedprc - is this a react component or just javascript?

Comment: react component

Comment: @sedprc - updated and testable @ stackblitz link

Comment: ok perfect but which is the right condition to show the description too?
i have modified in some way but the first loop skip the description.
here the reseult: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ja52hk?file=src/App.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233681/discussion-between-sedprc-and-kinglish).